# Is it possible to pass arguments to functions in a main.js file for an atom plugin?

Tags: javascript, arguments, atom-editor

I would like to have one method that I can call and pass in an argument based on the context menu item selected.

Can an argument be passed in from the cson file, or is it possible to just pass the value of the item clicked (like `item.label` or something similar)?

I have this in my lib\main.js file:

```
const MyAtomPlugin = {
  subscriptions: null,

  activate (state) {
    this.subscriptions = new CompositeDisposable();
    this.subscriptions.add(
      atom.commands.add('atom-text-editor', {
        'menu-item-label:toggle': this.method1
      })
    );
  },

  method1() {
    console.log(0);
  }
```

where the menu-item-label is in the menu.cson file for my package. The goal is to be able to have:

```
const MyAtomPlugin = {
  subscriptions: null,

  activate (state) {
    this.subscriptions = new CompositeDisposable();
    this.subscriptions.add(
      atom.commands.add('atom-text-editor', {
        'menu-item-label:toggle': this.method1
      })
    );
  },

  method1(variableName) {
    console.log(variableName);
  }
```

My menu file follows as:

```
{
  "context-menu": {
    "atom-text-editor": [
      {
        "label": "Button1",
        "submenu": [
          {
            "label": "SubMenuLabel",
            "command": "menu-item-label:toggle"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So I would like to select the SubMenuLabel button from the context menu, and pass its label as the argument: `variableName`